# text processor assignment setString method java

Tags: java

I'm having problems figuring out why my setMethod is not working. When i use it my main method doesn't display any correct answers. I originally used a user input into my StringProcessor str = new StringProcessor(input) which worked perfectly. I'm just not sure why i cant get it to work if i don't have input in my new object and use set string to created my string. Any help would be great. thanks.

```
import java.util.*;
public class StringProcessor {
private String noSpaces, string;
private String input, noVowels;
private String noDigitWords;
private int numOfWords = 0, uppercaseLetters = 0,
            numOfDigits = 0, digitWords = 0;
private String [] wordDigits = {"zero","one", "two", "three","four",
        "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
private String [] digits = {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4",
        "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};


public StringProcessor()
{
    string = ("");
}

public StringProcessor(String s)
{
    StringTokenizer one = new StringTokenizer(s);
    StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(s);
    numOfWords = str.countTokens();

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i)))
            uppercaseLetters++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)))
            numOfDigits++;
    }

    String [] strSplit = s.split(" ");
    for(int i = 0; i < strSplit.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < wordDigits.length; j++)
        {
            if (strSplit[i].equalsIgnoreCase(wordDigits[j]))
                    digitWords++;
        }
    }


    noSpaces = s.replace(" ","");
    noVowels = s.replaceAll("[aeiou]", "-");

    noDigitWords = s;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        noDigitWords = noDigitWords.replace(wordDigits[i],    digits[i]);
    }
}

public void setString(String s)
{
    string = s;
}

public String getString()
{
    return string;
}

public int wordCount()
{
    return numOfWords;
}

public int uppercaseCount()
{
    return uppercaseLetters;
}

public int digitCount()
{
    return numOfDigits;
}

public int digitWordCount()
{
    return digitWords;
}

public String getNoSpaceString()
{
    return noSpaces;
}

public String getNoVowelString()
{
    return noVowels;
}

public String getNoDigitWordString()
{
    return noDigitWords;
}
```

public static void main(String[] args)
    {

```
    StringProcessor str = new StringProcessor();
    str.setString("my string");
    System.out.println(str.getString());

    System.out.println("words: " + str.wordCount());
    System.out.println("uppercase: " + str.uppercaseCount());
    System.out.println("digits: " + str.digitCount());
    System.out.println("digit words " + str.digitWordCount());
    System.out.println("line with no spaces: " + str.getNoSpaceString());
    System.out.println("line with vowels replaced: " + str.getNoVowelString());
    System.out.println("line with digit words replaced: " + str.getNoDigitWordString());
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all the computation is done when you construct a `StringProcessor` with a string argument:

```
StringProcessor str = new StringProcessor("some string");
```

But you're not using that constructor; you're only using the constructor that takes no arguments.  Therefore the code that does all the computation never gets executed.

Move the computation to a private method.  Then have both the one-argument constructor and `setString` call that method.  (And make sure either `setString` or your private method reinitializes all the counts to 0, so that if you set `setString` multiple times, the values will be correct and not cumulative.)

Comment: The methods I have listed are the methods I'm supposed to use in my assignment. Should I copy all the work I have in the one method and then paste it to another?

Comment: @user3242607 I haven't seen the assignment, but it's possible that the "methods you're supposed to use" are the **public** methods that need to be available in your class to other classes outside that class.  A private method would be just a "helper" method used to help implement the public methods.  I don't see how your instructor could object to that, but in case they do, then I suppose cut-and-paste would work.  It's a horrible programming practice, but saying you can't use a private method would be a horrible restriction.